# How to do summation to infinity in this case in maple or mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, maple

maple code, no matter write this matrix in procedure or not, still get error, how to summation to infinity

```
DetAn:= (n)-> LinearAlgebra:-Determinant(
     Matrix(
          n, n,
          (i,j)->
               if j >= i and (j-i)::even then
                    (j-i+1)*(j-1)!/(i-1)!*a(j-i+1)*x
               elif i-j = 1 then  -1
               else  0
               end if
     )
):

Summation(DetAn(k)*z^k/k!, k=0..infinity);
```

**Update:**
a(i) could be a := t -> t^2

Answer (score 1):

You will get an error for the given input because the `sum` (or `Summation`) command has normal evaluation rules for procedure arguments and so will try to evaluate `DetAn(n)` for nonumeric symbolic `n`. You'd get the same error message (from the `Matrix` constructor) if you just called,

```
DetAn(n);
```

where n is an unassigned name.

But delaying that premature evaluation isn't going to get a result.

```
Summation('DetAn'(k)*z^k/k!, k=0..infinity);
```

`LinearAlgebra:-Determinant` is not going to cough up a closed form result for symbolic `n`. You can get a recursive summation formula for `DetAn(n)`, ie. as a sum of terms involving `DetAn(j-1)` or `DetAn(j-2)` from `j=1..n/2`. I don't know whether you could hammer on that for a generating function.

Consider what kind of answer you are looking for, if only from the `Determinant` call. Are hoping for a nested sum (nested to a fixed, finite depth)?

What is a(i)?

Why is the determinant in terms of powers of x, while z comes into the summation terms?

Comment: a(i) could be a := t -> t^2, any restriction on function a? i could not hammer on that for a generating function. the book Elliptic polynomial stated polynomial of det, is in terms of x and a(i)

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica can simply take infintiy as a limit:

```
Sum[(1/2)^i, {i, 0, Infinity}]

Out= 2
```

I didn't try with your example but its worth a shot.